# Deactivate css concat in meteor to use angular2 styleUrls

Tags: css, meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

Meteor concats all css in /client by default. In angular2 you can add styleUrls to your @View so your css file is only applied to that specific component. How can i deactivate meteors concating and thereby polluting the global css?

I know that you can place your css into /public so they don't get concatenated but i don't want to split my components across multiple folders.